# Swift Xcode 6.1.1 POST Request not posting

Tags: php, ios, xcode, post, swift

I simply want to POST some data from Swift to a PHP script. I've Googled for about two days on this and everyone seems to be doing the same thing, but it's not working for me. I have this Swift code triggered on viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/scriptToHandlePOST.php")!) // it forces me to add the !
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    let postString = "var1=value1&var2=value2".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var postLength:NSString = String( postString!.length )

    request.HTTPBody = postString
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error -> Void in
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println(response) // this returns a 200
        println(strData!) // this returns an empty array of the $_POST variable
    }

    task.resume() // this is needed to start the task

}
```

My PHP script is simply just trying to get $_POST data:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Since the $_POST returns an empty array I suspect the POST request is never making it to my website. Do you see anything wrong in the code?

Comment: You might also watch this exchange with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and see what's going back and forth. You should print something else in your php, and make sure you're getting responses successfully. I'd also delete the app and reinstall it and make sure you're not getting some weird caching problem. I'd also look at the `Content-Length` of the `response` object and see what it has.

Comment: Thanks I tried printing something else in PHP, reinstalling the app and looking at the content-length of the response. Here is what the request.HTTPBody is sending 
    `println(NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding: 
NSUTF8StringEncoding))`
    `//Optional(var1=value1&var2=value2)`
Response
`{ status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 48;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sat, 27 Dec 2014 17:39:08 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=98";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";`

Comment: Does the `Content-Length` of 48 make sense given your "empty array of the $_POST variable" output? Bottom line, there's nothing obvious here, which is why I'd watch this with Charles, so you can diagnose whether the problem is in the construction of the request, the PHP's generation of the response, or your println of the response. It would be good to narrow down the problem.

Comment: By the way, you said something about base64 string representation (which you subsequently removed). Is one of your post values a base64 string? Do you have newline characters in that base64 string? Have you percent-escaped it?

Comment: Eventually I'd like to do more complex things like file uploads but for now I just want to post very simple text data. I ran Charlie (cool app!) and it says the request method was GET instead of POST so I think something is wrong with the Swift code.

Comment: I tried your code (both client and server) on my end, and it works fine. We need a reproducible example in order to help you. Sometimes Xcode gets in weird state, so restarting Xcode (and sometimes even rebooting Mac) can help. Otherwise provide an example that reproduces the problem you describe.

Comment: By the way, as you contemplate more complicated things, you may be using `multipart/form-data` for file uploads. And you might want to return JSON response rather than `print_r`, because it's going to be easier for your app to parse. But like I said, the above `var1=value1&var2=value2` example works fine. I wouldn't worry about setting `Content-Length` as that's done for you transparently, but it doesn't cause a problem if you do it.

Comment: Rob thanks so much for your help and testing the code! I figured out the issue. I had an .htaccess redirect that was redirecting mysiteurl.com to www.mysiteurl.com and I was posting to mysiteurl.com. As soon as I switched to post to www.mysiteurl.com instead it worked. Hopefully this helps someone else...

Comment: Excellent. Yeah, I find Charles invaluable in tracking down these issues. Regardless, you should feel free to [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and "accept" it, as strange as that sounds) in order to close this.